# Size of Compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I was exploring a bit on compilers.I had a question in my mind.I wanted to know whether,
C-Programming language provide*any programing function* to know the **size of compiler** being used?

Comment: what do you mean by size of compiler ? size of the binaries in KB? Why would that be required?

Comment: Do you mean, perhaps, the width in bits (e.g. 16 or 32 or 64) of a "word"?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's safe to say "no". There isn't necessarily a meaningful answer -- it's entirely possible to build a single program with code from two (or more) different compilers.